# How differentiate data for each database or Graph

Tags: database, neo4j, rdbms, nosql

1. To differentiate data for each database , like in examples neo4j has
   movie db and northwind db, so how would we know at the end what
   sought of database/graphs we've. Any how these are managed (database
   administration point of view).
2. Secondly if we connect to sqlserver from its client and we can have
   list of database where each database has its own db objects. so how
   can we deal with below points:

   To execute a query on a particular database or graph , in sqlserver
   we can either use full qualified name under any db context e.g
   select * from Amazon.dbo.people or "Use Amazon" and call store
   procedures,views,functions or whatever objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neo4j does not have the concept of multiple databases in one Neo4j instance. But you can run multiple databases by setting up multiple instances - even on the same machine.

Another option is to organize your graph into multiple distinct subgraphs.

Comment: Any examples for setting you mutiple database on multiple instance. Any For seconds options, implies i need to create a root node in name of instance and subnodes to that root node  e.g. moviedb-->Instance<--Northwinddb. Will appreciate if subgraph example can be shared